# Why would the arctic have very short spring and autumn?

Tags: seasons

I read http://www.jeanlouisetienne.com/en/images/encyclo/imprimer/11.htm

that in the arctic, (and no doubt the antarctic - the pole regions), "Spring and autumn last just a few weeks each"

I understand that in the summer the earth is tilted such that the hemisphere where it is summer is tilted towards the sun so is at less of an angle from the sun. So hence in summer it's warmer and days are longer.  I understand that.

But I don't understand why spring and autumn should be shorter for countries near the poles.

I understand this diagram for seasons (and I understand that astronomical seasons are similar to meteriological seasons)

But that diagram doesn't even show a short autumn and spring at the poles (let alone indicate why)

[image]

I have heard that with rainforests they define seasons by rainfall, rather than earth's position in relation to the sun.  I don't know if poles are anything like that in that they somehow define seasons differently?